# mail() can't see Addressee after sending

Tags: php, email, sendmail, contacts

I've got a problem with this script

```
<?php
$to      = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: email2@exaple.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Script sends an email but I can't see Addressee. There is problem with $email variable. If I use `<?php echo $email ?>` I can see it.

There is a form

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
```

(...)

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: you shouldn't use the mail() function; there are a few good libraries out there to handle this for you:

PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

SwiftMailer: http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Also your $email var is fine; the problem is probably with your form.

Comment: What is the output of `echo "-".$email."-`? Maybe there's something in there, that shouldn't be in there. Better filter that first (via `$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` ).

Comment: echo returns me a variable. Why $subject and $message are ok? there are writen in the same way.